# How to calculate solar ecliptic longitude

Tags: orbit, solar-system, meteor

I would like to write a small script to calculate solar ecliptic longitude in relation to different locations and dates. For instance UTC + - 1...2 etc..
I know, solar ecliptic longitude is the position of the sun relative to the vernal equinox, in degrees clockwise 360 degrees over a year..

What do I have to keep in mind?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Looking down from above the North Pole, the solar ecliptic longitude increases in the anticlockwise direction. See https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ecliptic_with_earth_and_sun_animation.gif

Comment: What do you mean by *"in relation to different locations"*? Typically, the solar ecliptic longitude is calculated relative to the centre of the Earth. There is a small difference to the observed longitude at a given location on the Earth's surface due to parallax and atmospheric refraction. Of course, location (or time zone) is needed to convert local time to UTC.

Comment: Thanx, you helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you want to write this script in, but here is one way to calculate the solar longitude using astropy.

```
import astropy.time
import astropy.coordinates

time = astropy.time.Time("2023-03-29")

sun = astropy.coordinates.get_body("sun", time=time)
frame = astropy.coordinates.GeocentricTrueEcliptic(equinox=time)

lon = sun.transform_to(frame).lon.value

print(lon)
```

Which outputs

```
8.041066223269443
```